# The meaning of "mere" in Yeats's "The Second Coming"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Turning and turning in the widening gyre
>   The falcon cannot hear the falconer;
>   Things fall apart; the centre cannot hold;
>   *Mere anarchy* is loosed upon the world,

Can the adjective *mere* apply to "anarchy"? I've always taken it to mean the same thing as "only", in a dismissive way. E.g *He's merely a baby.* -> *He's only/just a baby*.

So does the phrase *mere anarchy* mean that the anarchy was nothing serious, not much to worry about?

Comment: This was a great question which got some really interesting responses. Thanks for asking it, I hope you ask some more!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Mere*, when it came into English from Latin and OF, meant “pure, unmixed”, and was usually used as Yeats uses it here: *mere anarchy* means absolute anarchy, sheer anarchy, anarchy unmixed with order, “nothing less than” anarchy.

*Mere* could of course also be used with deprecated qualities, with the complementary sense “nothing more than”: *mere folly* is folly unmixed with wisdom, *mere conjecture* is conjecture unmixed with fact, and that use predominates today. Dictionaries may call this “obsolete” or “archaic”, but it is at most an archaic use, not an archaic meaning.

Comment: The OED says the meaning *pure, unadulterated* has been obsolete for a long time, but *absolute*, *sheer* was around in the 19th century. The difference between these two definitions is not completely clear, but it seems that the first is more or less literal (*meer Chalk; earthly happiness is never mere*) and the second figurative.

Answer (score 7):

I think it refers to the *obsolete*  meaning of ***[mere](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mere)***:

> - pure.
> - absolute

The Free Dictionary

From [Yeatsvision.com](http://www.yeatsvision.com/secondnotes.html):

> - ***The word ‘Mere’ means both pure and only, and the first section further emphasises the generality and absoluteness of the situation with words such as ‘everywhere’ and ‘all’.***  The ‘Mere anarchy’ which is loosed (by whom?) like a plague or scourge then becomes a tide dimmed by blood, recalling the bloody seas of the Revelation of St John, the flood from the mouth of the serpent and the vials of wrath (Rev 8:8; 12:15; 16:1-4).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I believe the author is using 'mere' in the sense that anarchy is a state without order, a base existence. 'Mere' in this case amplifies the despair of the condition, a resolution of one's fate... At least, the way I read it.

Answer (score 0):

"Mere" here is used with the meaning of "unmitigated".

Comment: Can you specify your source please?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of "The Second Coming" this appears to mean total and unmitigated anarchy. How else could this be interpreted?  IMHO.